# Did Lopamudra ever receive Upanayana?

Tags: women, upanayanam

Lopamudra was a female Rishi who revealed Vedic mantras and did lots of Tapas, as per [*Mahabharata*](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03097.htm):

> And obtaining her as wife, Agastya addressed Lopamudra, saying, 'Cast
>   thou away these costly robes and ornaments.' And at these words of her
>   lord, that large-eyed damsel of thighs tapering as the stem of the
>   plantain tree cast away her handsome and costly robes of fine texture.
>   And casting them away she dressed herself in rags and barks and
>   deerskins, and became her husband's equal in vows and acts. And
>   proceeding then to Gangadwara that illustrious and best of Rishis
>   began to practise the severest penances along with his helpful wife.
>   And Lopamudra herself, well pleased, began to serve her lord from the
>   deep respect that she bore him. And the exalted Agastya also began to
>   manifest great love for his wife.
>
> After a considerable time, O king, the illustrious Rishi one day
>   **beheld Lopamudra, blazing in ascetic splendour** come up after the bath
>   in her season. And pleased with the girl, for her services, her
>   purity, and self control, as also with her grace and beauty, he
>   summoned her for marital intercourse.

Did Lopamudra ever receive Upanayana to do the tapas?

Comment: seeta also did sandhyavandanam. did she have yajnopavitam ? anyone who chants or receives vedic mntra shd have the samskara, its automatically understood..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Hmm, might be right.